# GitLab CI/CD pipeline rules with changes parameter not working for build job, how to fix?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have this code on my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - setup
  - train

.rules_non_prod:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^(development|staging|main)$/"
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: "feature"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

.rules_prod:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: prod

.tags_non_prod:
  - dev
  - mll

.tags_prod:
  - prod
  - mll

#======= BUILD
.build: &build
  stage: setup
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  dependencies: []
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - cd scripts/docker && sh login.sh
  script:
    - sh build.sh $CI_PROJECT_NAME $DOCKER_FOLDER

build:non-prod:
  <<: *build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      changes:
        - docker/**/*
      when: never
    - !reference [.rules_non_prod, rules]
  tags: !reference [.tags_non_prod]

build:prod:
  <<: *build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      changes:
        - docker/**/*
      when: never
    - !reference [.rules_prod, rules]
  tags: !reference [.tags_prod]
```

I would like to ensure that the “build” job only appears when there are changes in the files within the docker folder. To achieve this, I attempted to incorporate the “changes” parameter into the rules of the job, as you can see. However, this approach is not working as the “build” job consistently appears.

What I’m doing wrong?

Thank you.

NOTE: I have many other jobs that use that general rules.

Answer (score 0):

This was my best solution until now, but maybe there is a way not to have so many if/else.

```
stages:
  - build
  - auth
  - train

.variables_non_prod: &variables_non_prod
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: "feature"

.variables_prod: &variables_prod
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: prod

.rules_non_prod:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
      # if branch is not development, staging or main, set ENVIRONMENT to feature
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^(development|staging|main)$/ && $CI_JOB_STAGE != "build"
      <<: *variables_non_prod
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^(development|staging|main)$/ && $CI_JOB_STAGE == "build"
      changes:
        - docker/**/*
      <<: *variables_non_prod
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_JOB_STAGE != "build"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_JOB_STAGE == "build"
      changes:
        - docker/**/*

.rules_prod:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_JOB_STAGE != "build"
      <<: *variables_prod
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_JOB_STAGE == "build"
      changes:
        - docker/**/*
      <<: *variables_prod

#======= BUILD
.build: &build
  stage: build
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  dependencies: []
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - cd scripts/docker && sh login.sh
  script:
    - sh build.sh $CI_PROJECT_NAME $DOCKER_FOLDER

build:non-prod:
  <<: *build
  rules: !reference [.rules_non_prod, rules]
  tags: !reference [.tags_non_prod]

build:prod:
  <<: *build
  rules: !reference [.rules_prod, rules]
  tags: !reference [.tags_prod]
```